# Paypal express checkout using activemerchant and ipn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, paypal-ipn, activemerchant

I'm stuck with getting activemerchants paypal express ipn notification to work.

My workflow looks like this:

```
# authorize the payment user gets redirected..
def auth
  ...
  gateway.setup_authorization(total_as_cents, setup_authorization_params)
  ...
end

# purchase the authorized sum
def purchase
  ...
  purchase_params = {
    token: @order.payment_params[:token],
    payer_id: @order.payment_params[:payer_id],
    currency: current_tenant.currency.unit,
    notify_url: paypal_ipn_callback_url
  }
  response = gateway.purchase(total_as_cents, purchase_params)
  ...
end
```

In the paypal docs it says notify_url is deprecated they use PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NOTIFYURL instead. But I have no clue how to tell this my paypal express gateway.

My ipn callback doesn't get called so I assume the notifyurl param doesn't work anymore.
Paypal is in sandbox mode but that should make no difference right?

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you are using Paypal Express that means you are doing a deep integration with your system, and you don't need the IPN, you can get the response from

```
response = gateway.purchase(total_as_cents, purchase_params)
```

and get all information from it, and that response is an object

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressResponse
```

The IPN is used for the basic Paypal integration, with no API calls from your app, only Paypal URL redirect with params.

Comment: This is only true if you accepts only instant payments. If the response is "pending", for example, the notification when it is done can only be received with paypal ipn or periodically checking with paypal. Note that when there is currency conversion, it might return pending.